# v-for on every function execution

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I want to use v-for in a way that it makes a new li element every time a function is executed. Something like this

```
<ul>
    <li v-for:"someFunction()">Function started</li>
</ul>

new Vue({
    ...
    methods: {
        someFunction: function() {
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That's not how `v-for` works.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

You should create an array data property and push to it each time the function is called. Then use that property in the `v-for` directive:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { items: [] };
  },
  methods: {
    someFunction: function() {
      this.items.push({});
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">Function started</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button @click="someFunction">Call Function</button>
</div>
```

---

Or, if you simply need to keep track of the number of times the method was fired, you can pass `v-for` a number:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { count: 0 };
  },
  methods: {
    someFunction: function() {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in count">Function started</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button @click="someFunction">Call Function</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable :

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>

new Vue({
    ...
    data () {
      return {
         items: {message: 'Test 1', message: 'Test 2'}
      }
    },
    methods: {
        someFunction: function() {
            this.items.push( {message: 'Test 3'} )
        }
    }
});
```